# PyTorch ToTensor scaling to [0,1] discrepancy

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, mnist

If I do this

```
mnist_train = MNIST('../data/MNIST', download = True,
                transform = transforms.Compose([
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                ]), train = True)
```

and

`mnist_train.data.max()`

why do I get 255? I should get 1, because `ToTensor()` scales to `[0,1]`, right?

If  I do:

```
for i in range(0, len(mnist_train)):
    print(mnist_train[i][0].max())
```

then, I get almost `1`?

Could someone please help me understand this?

Comment: [Documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor) says "...In the other cases, tensors are returned without scaling."; so your case falls into one of those other cases?

Comment: I also printed the max values, which is the second part of the question, I get almost all `1`.

Comment: You are right! I wrote an answer as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
mnist_train.data
```

PyTorch gives you the `data` attribute of the `mnist_train`, which is defined on [this line](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L93) (when you make a MNIST instance). And if you look at the codes before it in the `__init__`, no transformation happens!

OTOH, when you do

```
mnist_train[i]
```

the `__getitem__` method of the object is triggered which you can find [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L119-L139).  There is an `if` statement for `transform` in this method and therefore you get the transformed version now.

Since a common usage is using this MNIST dataset (or any other one) through `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` and it calls this `__getitem__`, we get the normalized values.